# Ubuntu 20.04 not using full display

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, display, intel-graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC (Intel Core i7 11700 with UHD Graphics 750). I'm using a LG 32ul950-w display via DisplayPort cable. But KDE does not use the full screen (see picture). It cuts off a small part off the lower display.

The resolution of the monitor is 3840 x 2160, which is also shown by KDE as the current setting. The aspect ratio of the monitor is 16:9, but KDE does not show any information about the aspect ratio used.
It is probably not an hardware issue, because Windows 10 runs perfectly fine on the same machine.

[image: Photo of Gap]

Is there anything thing i can do to use the full display? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. We are Ubuntu users from all over the world. Brand name and model numbers don't always tell us much as the same monitor may be sold in different parts of the world under different model numbers. Similarly, internal specifications of two monitors with the same model number may be different. What are the display resolutions supported by your monitor? What is the aspect ration of your monitor? What does the Kubuntu display settings show in terms of screen resolution and aspect ratio? Please **edit your question** and add these information.

Comment: Are you sure the wallpaper is large enough or set to stretch?

Comment: Yes, i dont even see the menu bar. When i use applications in fullscreen the lower part is still missing. It is also not a desktop environment issue. The same thing happens when i use GNOME.
The weird thing is, the color of the missing part is changing accordingly to the color of the rest of the display.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use an (K)Ubuntu Live USB and and use the Try Ubuntu option? This is to rule out some settings modifications in your custom system is causing this.  If you do get this problem in the Live USB, then there are two possibilities. First, it is a bug. Second, it is a hardware problem. I think Windows is much more forgiving than Ubuntu when it comes to hardware issues.

Comment: The issue also occurs on the Live USB version. I think a hardware problem is the most unlikely possibility because the BIOS is displayed full screen without any problems.

Comment: Apparently it was a software problem. I just updated to 21.04 and the problem is gone. Thanks for your input!